For a square matrix $A$, if $\dim(ker(A - 2I) = 3$, then its characteristic polynomial is of the form ($\lambda - 2)^3$ * q ($\lambda$)
For a square matrix $A$, if $\dim(ker(A - 2I) = 3$, then its characteristic polynomial is of the form ($\lambda - 2)^3$ * q  ($\lambda$) for some polynomial q.
My approach: So we know that A has an eigenvalue 2 with GM = 3 and since AM >= GM then the
the characteristic polynomial is valid since its exponent for ($\lambda - 2)^3$ is at least 3.
Is that a reasonable way to conclude that this statement about characteristic polynomial is true?

I would argue via the Jordan decomposition of $A$. In the end, this is probably the same as your argument.

The final factor $\lambda$ in the proposed form of the characteristic polynomial seems to be a mistake. Consider, for example, the $3\times3$ matrix $A=2I$.  Was $q*\lambda$ perhaps intended to be $q(\lambda)$ ?

@AndreasBlass you are right

Your proof is correct, but what does "the characteristic polynomial is valid" mean? You likely mean "the characteristic polynomial has a factorization of the given form".
Sometimes it's nice to remember a proof of the inequality you cited, one approach to which uses the following trick that's useful. Essentially, one observes that $A$ is similar to a partially diagonalized matrix.
Let $V$ be a nonsingular square matrix whose first 3 columns comprise a basis of the 2-eigenspace of $A$, denote by $V_1$ the first 3 columns of $V$, and by $V_2$ the rest. Then $$AV = [V(2[e_1\ e_2\ e_3]) \mid AV_2] = [V(2[e_1\ e_2\ e_3]) \mid VV^{-1}AV_2] = V[2[e_1\ e_2\ e_3] \mid B]$$
where $e_i$ is a standard basis basis vector and $B=V^{-1}AV_2$. You can see directly that $A$ is similar to a matrix whose characteristic polynomial has the form $(\lambda-2)^3 q(\lambda)$ for some polynomial $q$.
